# Modifying DOM to style sequential headings

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

Let's start with this html in my database table:

```
<section id="love">
<h2 class="h2Article">III. Love</h2>
<div class="divArticle">
```

This is what the display looks like after I run it through a DOM script:

```
<section id="love"><h2 class="h2Article" id="a3" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#b3">III. Love</h2>
<div class="divArticle collapse in article" id="b3">
```

And this is what I would like it to look like this:

```
<section id="love"><h2 class="h2Article" id="a3" data- toggle="collapse" data-target="#b3">
    <span class="Article label label-primary">
        <i class="only-collapsed fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
        <i class="only-expanded fa fa-remove"></i> III. Love</span></h2>
<div class="divArticle collapse in article" id="b3">
```

In other word, DOM has given it the necessary function, correctly numbering each id sequentially. All that's missing is the styling:

```
<span class="Article"><span class="label label-primary"><i class="only- collapsed fa fa-chevron-down"></i><i class="only-expanded fa fa-remove"> </i> III. Love</span></span>
```

Can anyone tell me how to add that styling? The titles will change, of course (e.g. III. Love, IV. Hate, etc.). I posted my DOM script below:

```
$i = 1; // initialize counter
$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($Content); // load the markup
$sections = $dom->getElementsByTagName('section'); // get all section tags
    foreach($sections as $section) { // for each section tag

        // get div inside each section
        foreach($section->getElementsByTagName('h2') as $h2) {
            if($h2->getAttribute('class') == 'h2Article') { // if this div has class maindiv
                $h2->setAttribute('id', 'a' . $i); // set id for div tag
                $h2->setAttribute('data-target', '#b' . $i);
            }
        }

        foreach($section->getElementsByTagName('div') as $div) {
            if($div->getAttribute('class') == 'divArticle') { // if this div has class divArticle
                $div->setAttribute('id', 'b' . $i); // set id for div tag
            }

            if($div->getAttribute('class') == 'divClose') { // if this div has class maindiv
                $div->setAttribute('data-target', '#b' . $i); // set id for div tag
            }
        }
        $i++; // increment counter
    }

// back to string again, get all contents inside body
$Content = '';
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)->childNodes as $child) {
    $Content .= $dom->saveHTML($child); // convert to string and append to the container
}

$Content = str_replace('data-target', 'data-toggle="collapse" data-target', $Content);
$Content = str_replace('<div class="divArticle', '<div class="divArticle collapse in article', $Content);
```

Comment: Is there any logic that needs to be implemented to determine which styles get added when, or are you just wondering how to add a chunk of HTML inside your PHP code?

Comment: It would be really cool to learn how to add a little logic. For example, the last h2 heading in each article has a distinct style - but I handled that by simply putting it in a separate field in my database table. So right now, my most urgent need is to just add the HTML (and hope it doesn't somehow override the styles on my last heading).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I guess the obvious solution is to just wrap the title in something that can be modified with a simple str_replace...

```
<h2><span class="Answer">IIII. Love</span></h2>
```

Or even this...

```
<h2>[]III. Love[]</h2>
```

Kind of Mickey Mouse, but it gets the job done. I just having to write out or paste all of that code into every heading in every article. I prefer to automate it as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Since in this case a DOM Document object is being used, the createElement function can be used to add HTML.

See http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createelement.php

And stealing from the documentation on the attached page

```
<?php

$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');

$element = $dom->createElement('test', 'This is the root element!');

// We insert the new element as root (child of the document)
$dom->appendChild($element);

echo $dom->saveXML();
?>
```

will output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<test>This is the root element!</test>
```

---

Without the DOM object, you would normally add PHP in one of the following ways.

1.

```
echo "<div>this method is often used for shorter pieces of HTML</div>";
```

2.

```
?> <div> You can also escape out of HTML and then "turn" PHP back on like this </div> <?php
```

The first method uses the echo command to output a string of HTML. The second  method uses the 
 `?>` escape tag to tell the computer to start treating everything as HTML until it sees another opening `<?php` PHP tag.

So normally in a PHP file you can add HTML like so.

```
?> 
   <span class="Article">
       <span class="label label-primary">
           <i class="only- collapsed fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
           <i class="only-expanded fa fa-remove"></i> 
           III. Love
       </span>
    </span>
<?php
```

But since in this case we're trying to edit content coming from inside of the database we're not able to do this.

Comment: I don't think that will work with database output, will it? The headers all have different titles (e.g. Love, Hate, etc.).

Comment: your right. I'm not used to seeing PHP code the way you're doing it. The following should help you out. I'll update my answer to reflect this. http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createelement.php